# form submit message duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am submitting my form with ajax and jquery ,, but the problem is that the error message is duplicated on every time form submits . What could be the problem ?

js file

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#checkit").click(function(){
 var ID = $("#certcode").val();


      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/icac/cert-check-ajax.php",
    data: 'z='+ ID,
    success: function(data) {
          $("#datadisp").append(data);

         $('#certcode').val('');
         return false;
    }

        }); 
});
});
```

php

```
<?php 
 include('/includes/db-connect.php');

if (!empty($_POST["z"]) ) {
    $z = $_POST["z"];
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `certificate_acheived_tbl` WHERE `cert_check_code` = '$z'");

if( mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {   


           echo '<div id="datadisp" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Certificate Found</div';


}

    else {     echo '<div id="datadisp" class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Invalid Security Code</div>';}
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post your html code too. If you are using a input tye=sybmit which id is "#checkit", you must do a event.preventDefault at the begining of your event function.

Comment: You are using `.append()` may be you need to use `.html()`/`replaceWith()`

Comment: <input value="check" name="checkits" id="checkit" type="button" class="btn btn-success">

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by 
  $("#datadisp").empty(); 
          $("#datadisp").html(data);